# Can’t compile WebView2 project. Need own Callback class template

Tags: c++, winapi, webview, com, windows-10-sdk

I am using Visual Studio 2015, version 14.0.23107.0. Project’s target platform is 10.0.17763.0.

I have read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/win32) article, and did first steps. I downloaded webview2 solution from [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/tree/master/GettingStartedGuides/Win32_GettingStarted) and opened it in Visual Studio. Then, via git NuGet I successfully added Windows Implementation Library package (version 1.0.200902.2), and WebView2 package (version 0.9.579).

Then, in `HelloWebView.cpp` I added

```
#include "WebView2.h"
```

At the start I couldn’t compile it. There was no errors in `HelloWebView.cpp` and in `WebView2.h`. The problem was in Windows Implementation Library.

Asking on Russian stack overflow [I got the solution](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1175994/379723) - do not include Windows Implementation Library, but ATL instead, and

```
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Controller> webviewController;

// Pointer to WebView window
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2> webviewWindow;
```

Replace with

```
static CComPtr<ICoreWebView2Controller> webviewController;

// Pointer to WebView window
static CComPtr <ICoreWebView2> webviewWindow;
```

And remove `using::Microsoft`;

After that, project compiles, but link fails - `LINK1158 error, can’t run rc.exe`. The solution was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14373113/12450770) (need to copy rc.exe and rcdll.dll to some folder).

Now it compiles and works.

So, I come to next step from the article and add code to create webview and open url, but again can’t compile it. There is only one problem - missed `Callback` template class from Windows Implementation Library.

So the only thing I need to do, to completely solve the problem is to provide my own template `Callback` class. But how to do that?

Current critical section (Callback is marked as an error)

```
CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr,
Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(
  [hWnd](HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Environment* env) -> HRESULT {

// Create a CoreWebView2Controller and get the associated CoreWebView2 whose parent is the main window hWnd
env->CreateCoreWebView2Controller(hWnd, Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler>(
  [hWnd](HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Controller* controller) -> HRESULT {
  if (controller != nullptr) {
    webviewController = controller;
    webviewController->get_CoreWebView2(&webviewWindow);
  }

  // Add a few settings for the webview
  // The demo step is redundant since the values are the default settings
  ICoreWebView2Settings* Settings;
  webviewWindow->get_Settings(&Settings);
  Settings->put_IsScriptEnabled(TRUE);
  Settings->put_AreDefaultScriptDialogsEnabled(TRUE);
  Settings->put_IsWebMessageEnabled(TRUE);

  // Resize WebView to fit the bounds of the parent window
  RECT bounds;
  GetClientRect(hWnd, &bounds);
  webviewController->put_Bounds(bounds);

  // Schedule an async task to navigate to Bing
  webviewWindow->Navigate(L"https://www.bing.com/");

  // Step 4 - Navigation events

  // Step 5 - Scripting

  // Step 6 - Communication between host and web content

  return S_OK;
}).Get());
return S_OK;
}).Get());
```

`Callback` declaration from Windows Implementation Library:

```
template<typename TDelegateInterface, typename TLambda>
ComPtr<typename Details::DelegateArgTraitsHelper<TDelegateInterface>::Interface> Callback(TLambda&& callback) throw()
{
using DelegateHelper = Details::DelegateArgTraitsHelper<TDelegateInterface>;
return DelegateHelper::Traits::template Callback<TDelegateInterface, typename DelegateHelper::Interface>(Details::Forward<TLambda>(callback));
}
```

Source code: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/tree/master/GettingStartedGuides/Win32_GettingStarted.

---

I don’t know, I don’t really a fan of c++11,14 features I didn’t work a lot with lambdas and I also (bet not only I) don’t like stuff like templates.

Maybe just to call code after?

Comment: I followed the article to try to reproduce your problem, but the problem you mentioned did not appear. I am using vs2019, and vs2017 can also successfully compile the code.

Comment: By the way, there may be other problems with the old version of VS. I suggest you use VS2017 or VS2019 before debugging.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT it is very uncomfortable, I need to do all tries with VS15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems hard nights do their work.
I included only `WRL`:

```
#include <wrl.h>
```

And then used:

```
Microsoft::WRL::Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(...
```

For each appearance and it compiled.

But it again was a blank window

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59900838/12450770) helped me, and now I finally got working solution I need.