# WebView2 runtime .dll problem loading on 64bit executables

Tags: delphi, webview2

I have tried having the WebView2Loader.dll in the same directory as my executable. And I have also *instead* to tried to download the evergreen build from  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/ and install it into my system  (and have *LoadLibrary* find the DLL there instead)

In both cases the following happens. In my 32bit executable builds everything loads and works fine. In my 64bit executable my code:

```
Windows.LoadLibrary(PChar('WebView2Loader.dll'))
```

Gives this error:

> %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I am on latest Windows 10 64bit

Any ideas what I can try...?

Comment: Presumably you have separate `.dll`:s for 32 and 64 bit. Do you adjust the `.dll` name accordingly (you show only one `LoadLibrary()` call) ?

Comment: From reading support forums Microsoft state it is the same dll should work for both 32bit and 64bit.. (Maybe their DLL is 32bit?) And I can not find webview2 installer path when using evergreen, I have searched entire windows system... But also strange if evergreen would install non 64bit dll on my 64bit Windows.

Comment: Looking at the download page (your link) there are separate installers for x86, x64 and ARM64.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I actually also tried the 64bit installer on Microsoft page. Can you let me know the exact paths on your system?

Comment: @TomBrunberg I know I must have webview2 installed because I have it in add/remove + 32bit application works when loading without the .dll in its directory, but I can not find any relevant .dll file anywhere. If you/anyone could give me examples of the physical names and addresses of the .dll files on your system I could try again (not easy to Google paths by the way.... Tried that) I guess next up must be to install something that watches file system during installation... But if anyone has any ideas... or Path examples, so I can manually search for and specify them for loadlibrary then....

Comment: If you use the Microsoft installers, I don't think you need to know the actual paths. The `.dll` files will be installed in the normal `.dll` search paths.

Comment: ...which is the whole point of _installing_ anything: to not take care oneself. Otherwise don't mix different architectures: either a DLL is for 32bit **or** 64bit (or 16bit), never multiple architectures. And those DLLs might import themselves DLLs, which should then be the same architecture (a 32bit DLL loading a 64bit DLL will also fail).

Comment: @TomBrunberg Thank you for the paths. Unfortunately the Microsoft installer fails working properly with the 32/64bit issue, so I need to know paths to investigate the problem.

Comment: @AmigoJack I agree it is a complete mess that the Microsoft installer apparently only installs 32bit dll on my system and LoadLibrary tries to load that when called from my 64bit executable. (Personally I still release 32 and 64 versions of my own software. But definitely unacceptable only 32bit WebView2 dll is working properly)

Comment: @TomBrunberg I unfrotunately do not have any such path "C:\Program Files (x86)\product\product\product\"  and searching for WebView2Loader.dll in "C:\Program Files (x86)\" fails :( ... and yes in Add/Remove WebView2 is listed as installed (and apparently works for 32bit executables)

Comment: @TomBrunberg I interpreted it as possible meaning 3rd party as relative to your own distribution of webview2 (i.e. possibly Microsoft)  Anyhow then, my problem persist, I can not find any dlls of such name on my system even though searching my entire computer again and again including program files / program files (x86) folders. (Which is why I mentioned I had tried searching the root) I guess I will have to install something that watches my entire file system while installing the WebView2 evergreen distriubtion by Microsoft. Thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: For others reading this is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59711826/chromium-edge-based-webview2-does-not-work ... seems the dll can also be called EmbeddedBrowserWebView.dll so now I can figure out what the evergreen package actually installed :)

Comment: I deleted most of my comments as they are of no value for other readers. I suggest you do the same.